# How can i restart windows server 2016 via c# statement?

Tags: reboot, c#, windows-server

I have a web app that run in windows server 2016.

I am going to restart windows by c# command.

This possible in windows 10 by `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 0");` statment.

But this code dont restart windows server.

How can i do this?

Comment: First thing I'd guess is that the process doesn't have enough privileges. Check if the environment it is running within has enough rights to shutdown the server. Second, most console commands return a state to the caller check that it's not an error state.

Comment: How can i check this process have enough privileges? This statment run inside web app via IIS !